# Running Nested Command Lines with HERE

Tags: linux, ssh, sh

This command `myprogram.sh` command in CygWin installed with Chocolatey, called from the Windows Command Line, with an alias `server01` created at the `.ssh` folder, everything works fine:

```
# File myprogram.sh
ssh -p 66622 user@localhost << HERE
ssh server01 << EOF
    command1
    command2
EOF
HERE
```

Because i have several servers, i have to build several `.sh` files for different set of commands, so i have to create a lot of `.sh` files

But i've been unable to run the same instructions from a single line from the command line. Is that possible, in order to run these chain of instructions from a same place?

Comment: Have you heard of shell functions?

Answer (score 1):

```
#!/bin/bash
array=(server1 server2 server3 .... serverN)  
for i in ${array[@]}  
do  
    echo ${i}
    ssh  -p 66622 user@${i} "command1" 
done
```

you can change the "command1" to "command.sh"

Comment: I am looking for a way of not having a separate `.sh` file for every command tequired to be run.

Comment: you may  try  “Ansible” ，can send commands to many servers you defined in Host file